# What does this regex mean in PHP?

Tags: php, regex

```
/(?![a-z]+:)/
```

Anyone knows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the `/` are delimiters.

`?!` is [negative lookahead.](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

`[a-z]` is a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) (any character in the a-z range)

`+` is [one-or-more times](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) of the preceding pattern (`[a-z]` in this case)

`:` is just the colon literal

It roughly means "look ahead and make sure there are no alpha characters followed by a colon".

This regex would make more sense if it had a start of string anchor: `/^(?![a-z]+:/`, so it wouldn't match `abc:` (like one of the other answers say), but without the (`^`) I don't  know how useful this is.

Answer (score 2):

according to [Regex Buddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/) (a product i highly recommend):

```
Assert that it is impossible to match the regex below starting at this position (negative lookahead) «(?![a-z]+:)»
   Match a single character in the range between “a” and “z” «[a-z]+»
      Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
   Match the character “:” literally «:»
```

Answer (score 0):

`(?!REGEX)` is the syntax for [negative lookahead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973436/regex-lookahead-lookbehind-and-atomic-groups/2973609#2973609). Check the link for an explanation of lookaheads.

The regex fails if the pattern `[a-z]+:` appear in the string from the current position. If the pattern is not found, regex would succeed, but won't consume any characters.

It would match `123:` or `abc` <s>but not `abc:`</s>

It would match the `:` in `abc:`.

Comment: Nope, that's [not right.](http://rubular.com/r/sGqgeS5yPi). It still matches `abc:`

Comment: @Aillyn I don't see how the regex would be useful without some pattern before or after the lookahead.